# Equations and Double Spacing

Tags: equations, line-spacing

If a document (in any class) is double spaced, how do you redefine the spacing around centered equations as if there was single spacing? Whenever I use double spacing, I feel like the space before and after a centered equations is too large.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using the `setspace` package to change to doublespacing, you could use the `etoolbox` package and its `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` and `\AfterEndEnvironment` to append `\begin{singlespace}` before, and `\end{singlespace}` after the environments for displayed equations. The following example illustrates this approach for the `equation` and `align` environments (similar declarations will have to be made for the other environments and for their starred versions):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{equation}{\begin{singlespace}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{equation}{\end{singlespace}\noindent\ignorespaces}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{align}{\begin{singlespace}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{align}{\end{singlespace}\noindent\ignorespaces}

\doublespacing

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}
a=b.
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: What does \lipsum[2] mean?

Comment: @AlexRichter The [lipsum](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) package generates filler text; `lipsum[2]` means "use the second paragraph of the predefined text"; more generally, `\lipsum[i-j]` (with `i<j`) means "use the paragraphs i to j of the predefined text".

Comment: @AlexRichter: Mico's answer is better and you should accept it instead of mine.

Comment: It seems Mico's answer is not the same as this answer. Using `nodisplayskipstretch` does not make `align` environments singlespaced. However, this answer definitely does.

Comment: @Umang - I only now noticed your comment, which you posted nearly 5 years ago. Your application, which appears to involve `align` environments, is fundamentally different from what the OP posted and the answers provided by both Gonzalo Medina and myself, which treated single-line equations.

Answer (score 16):

You could simply set the `nodisplayskipstretch` option of the `setspace` package, viz., write

```
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
```

in the preamble. An advantage of this solution is that it applies automatically to *all* display-math environments. (Aside: In the MWE below, the `\namdui` command serves to produce some filler text -- specifically, the first few sentences of the second stanza of the `lipsum` package's text.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}

\newcommand{\namdui}{Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, 
sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, 
pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus.}  % filler text

\doublespacing   
\begin{document}

\namdui
\begin{equation}
a=b.
\end{equation}
\namdui
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

A potentially better alternative to `setspace` with `nodisplayskipstretch` or `etoolbox` is instead to use `setspace` as follows:

```
\usepackage{setspace}\setdisplayskipstretch{}
```

This usually results in a more compact document.  For example, the following code produces a document with 77 pages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}  %  For a consistent page count, specify a paper size.
\usepackage{setspace}\setdisplayskipstretch{}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{blindtext}  %  Introduces the "Lorem ipsum..." filler text command \blindtext
\usepackage{pgffor}     %  Introduces the \foreach command

\begin{document}
  \foreach \n in {1,...,200}{  % repeat 200 times
    \begin{equation}
      a=b.
    \end{equation}
    \blindtext  % "Lorem ipusm..." filler text
  }
\end{document}
```

In comparison, the page counts corresponding to the various possible `setspace` commands are:

```
╔════════════╦════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Page count ║ setspace command                                   ║
╠════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║         77 ║ \usepackage{setspace}\setdisplayskipstretch{}      ║
║         80 ║ Gonzalo Medina's answer using etoolbox             ║
║         81 ║ \usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}        ║
║         86 ║ \usepackage{setspace}                              ║
║         93 ║ \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2} % (no setspace) ║
╚════════════╩════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

#### Explanation

I will contrast `\usepackage{setspace}\setdisplayskipstretch{}` with `\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}`.  Looking into [`setspace.sty`](https://github.com/rf-latex/setspace/blob/master/setspace.sty), we see the following relevant lines:

```
\newcommand{\displayskipstretch}{\baselinestretch}
\newcommand{\setdisplayskipstretch}[1]{\renewcommand{\displayskipstretch}{#1}}
\DeclareOption{nodisplayskipstretch}{\setdisplayskipstretch{1.0}}
```

```
\everydisplay\expandafter{%
  \the\everydisplay
  \abovedisplayskip \displayskipstretch\abovedisplayskip
  \belowdisplayskip \displayskipstretch\belowdisplayskip
  \abovedisplayshortskip \displayskipstretch\abovedisplayshortskip
  \belowdisplayshortskip \displayskipstretch\belowdisplayshortskip
}
```

Therefore, the option `nodisplayskipstretch` is equivalent to setting the factor `\displayskipstretch=1.0`.  One may expect that multiplying by 1 should do nothing, but of course TeX is not that simple.  ;)  [The `displayskip` commands are `<glue>` types](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/%5Cabovedisplayskip%20and%20related%20commands), which means they contain a ± range called "stretch and shrink."  [Multiplying by 1 removes the stretch and shrink](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342175/remove-stretch-and-shrink-glue-from-existing-length), because [it converts `<glue>` to `<dimen>`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198954/scaling-a-glue-in-tex).  Thus `setspace` normally clobbers TeX's built-in flexibility to shrink the gaps above and below equations.  The `\setdisplayskipstretch{}` command prevents the multiplication, preserving the `<glue>` which allows the gaps to shrink.  That's why the resulting page count is lower.

Many thanks to [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) for [explaining to me what was going on](https://github.com/rf-latex/setspace/issues/1).

Comment: you are correct. `\usepackage{setspace}\setdisplayskipstretch{}` is best.