# Centering an equation that's wider than \textwidth?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

What to do if one want's to center an equation that's to wide for the margins and the equation isn't possible to split between rows like my example where there is a big fraction containing Mclaurinexpansions.

I'm searching for solutions that either just center the equation on the a4 paper or that can scale down the size of the equation so it fits.

Thanks in advance for shared knowledge!

There are some similar subjects already but I'm not satisfied with the answers there so I ask and add a picture.

[image: Visualization of the centering problem]

Comment: `\usepackage{mathtools}` then put a `\mathclap` around the complete equation, like so: `\begin{equation}\mathclap{my really long formula}\end{equation}`.

Comment: Can't you factor out the denominator, put a big parenthesis and split the numerator on multiple lines? Personally, I'd prefer to see this than an equation that goes over into the margin, or a reduced fontsize.

Comment: Just realizing that `\mathclap` might put the equation number over the equation.

Comment: off topic: don't forget to use `\cdots` after the minus sign.

Comment: hm could test the \mathclap, worst case I will skipp the equation number and add it manually with hyper ref in the text above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\noindent
\makebox[\textwidth]{\parbox{1.3\textwidth}{%
  \begin{align}
  y &= f(x)\\
  khdakshdkashdkajhsdkjahsdkh &= ksdjhf lksjdh fkjsdh fökjH SDÖKJFH ÖDFH öDFH 
  KSHDFKS
  \end{align}
}}
```

[image]

However, it makes more sense to split the formular in pieces.

Comment: If this is being submitted for publication, please make sure that the width of the centered equation doesn't exceed the width of the paper the document will be printed on.  Although you *should* get a warning from the publication office, these days you may not, and one or both ends of the equation could be cut off, or buried in the spine, and thus be lost.  It's always safer to reduce the width to fit within the specified margins.

Answer (score 2):

I propose three other possible layouts, with `mathtools` and/or `nccmath`:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
 \usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{fleqn}[-0.75em]
 \begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}[b]
  &\hspace{0.67em} f(x) = \\
   & \frac{\Bigl(6x-x^2 + \cfrac{x^5}{20}-\dotsm\Bigr) +\Bigl(x^3-\cfrac{x^6}{2} + \cfrac{x^9}{3}-\dotsm\Bigr) + \Bigl(x^3-\cfrac{x^6}{2} + \cfrac{x^9}{3}-\dotsm\Bigr)-6x}%
 {\Bigl(x^3-\cfrac{2x^5}{3} + \cfrac{23x^7}{45}-\dotsm\Bigr)-x^3}
 \end{aligned}
 \end{equation}
 \end{fleqn}
\bigskip

      \begin{equation}
      f(x) = \mfrac{\Bigl(6x-x^2 + \cfrac{x^5}{20}-\dotsm\Bigr) +\Bigl(x^3-\cfrac{x^6}{2} + \cfrac{x^9}{3}-\dotsm\Bigr) + \Bigl(x^3-\cfrac{x^6}{2} + \cfrac{x^9}{3}-\dotsm\Bigr)-6x}%
      {\Bigl(x^3-\cfrac{2x^5}{3} + \cfrac{23x^7}{45}-\dotsm\Bigr)-x^3}
      \end{equation}
\bigskip

      \begin{equation}
      f(x) = \frac{\splitfrac{\Bigl(6x-x^2 + \cfrac{x^5}{20}-\dotsm\Bigr) +\Bigl(x^3-\cfrac{x^6}{2} + \cfrac{x^9}{3}-\dotsm\Bigr)} {+ \Bigl(x^3-\cfrac{x^6}{2} + \cfrac{x^9}{3}-\dotsm\Bigr)-6x}}%
      {\Bigl(x^3-\cfrac{2x^5}{3} + \cfrac{23x^7}{45}-\dotsm\Bigr)-x^3}
      \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is an another way to centre an equation that is too wide to fit within the text area. It is similar to the solution proposed by Skillmon in [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462174/centering-an-equation-thats-wider-than-textwidth#comment1162366_462174), but it wraps your equation in a box whose width is exactly the maximal of the equation instead of one of width zero. This causes the equation number to be pushed to the next line, as desired.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe} %% <- Makes the text margins visible
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \makebox[\displaywidth]{$\displaystyle
      f(x) =
        \frac{
          \Bigl( 6x - x^2 + \dfrac{x^5}{20} - \dotsb \Bigr)
          + \Bigl( x^3 - \dfrac{x^6}{2} + \dfrac{x^9}{3} - \dotsb \Bigr)
          + \Bigl( x^3 - \dfrac{x^6}{2} + \dfrac{x^9}{3} - \dotsb \Bigr)
          - 6x
        }{
          \Bigl( x^3 - \dfrac{2x^5}{3} + \dfrac{23x^7}{45} - \dotsb \Bigr) - x^3
        }
    $}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The code is probably mostly self-explanatory, but here is a short explanation anyway:

- `\makebox[<width>]{<content>}` creates a box of width `<width>` that contains `<content>` (centred).
- `\displaywidth` is the maximum width of the current display math environment.
- `$\displaystyle <equation>$` produces an equation set in display style (with large fractions, summation symbols etc.).

---

### Alternative: reduce the amount of empty space in the equation

As an alternative to allowing your equations to stick out of the margins, I suggest reducing the amount of space between its constituents. This can be done as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} %% <- Makes the text margins visible
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*\squeezespaces[1]{% %% <- #1 is a number between 0 and 1
  \thickmuskip=\scalemuskip{\thickmuskip}{#1}% %% <- around =, \rightarrow, etc.
  \medmuskip=\scalemuskip{\medmuskip}{#1}%     %% <- around +, \times, etc.
  \thinmuskip=\scalemuskip{\thinmuskip}{#1}%   %% <- around \sum, \sin, etc.
  \nulldelimiterspace=#1\nulldelimiterspace    %% <- around fractions
  \scriptspace=#1\scriptspace                  %% <- after sub-/superscripts
}
\newcommand*\scalemuskip[2]{% %% <- scales muskips, including stretch/shrink
  \muexpr #1*\numexpr\dimexpr#2pt\relax\relax/65536\relax
} %% <- based on  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198966/156366

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \squeezespaces{.6}
    f(x) =
      \frac{
        \Bigl( 6x - x^2 + \dfrac{x^5}{20} - \dotsb \Bigr)
        + \Bigl( x^3 - \dfrac{x^6}{2} + \dfrac{x^9}{3} - \dotsb \Bigr)
        + \Bigl( x^3 - \dfrac{x^6}{2} + \dfrac{x^9}{3} - \dotsb \Bigr)
        - 6x
      }{
        \Bigl( x^3 - \dfrac{2x^5}{3} + \dfrac{23x^7}{45} - \dotsb \Bigr) - x^3
      }
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Squeezed to 60%]

The three lengths `\thickmuskip`, `\medmuskip` and `\thinmuskip` determine the amount of space that is inserted between various types of math atoms (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81777/156366) for a nice overview of when each is used). `\nulldelimiterspace` and `\scriptspace` are inserted around fractions and after sub-/superscripts respectively.
I'm reducing each of them to 60% of their original values (within this equation only).

If you want the equation number to appear on the same line you can of course compress the equation even further.
The following image was produced by replacing `.6` by `.45` in the previous document.

[image: Squeezed to 45%]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add `\hss` to both sides of the equation:

```
\hsize=7cm

\hbox to\hsize{|:left margin \hss text \hss right margin:|}

$$
 \hss This is an equation which slightly exceeds margins \hss
$$
```