# How to enforce the font not to be bold in {\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, journal, twoside]{ieeetran}}

Tags: fonts, ieeetran, bold, ieee-style

I need to submit a paper to IEEE Control System Letters Journal. In the instructions, I am told to use `\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, journal, twoside]{ieeetran}` as the document class.
My problem is that all the main texts are in Bold font which should not be.

Is there any command that can force the font of each section to be not Bold?

Thanks

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, journal, twoside]{IEEEtran}

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts     
\overrideIEEEmargins                                      % Needed 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xmpmulti}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{rotating}



\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}  
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\let\proof\relax  \let\endproof\relax
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,graphicx}
\let\proof\relax  \let\endproof\relax
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}


%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=0.7in, right=0.7in, bottom=0.6in, top=0.8in]{geometry}
\let\oldIEEEkeywords\IEEEkeywords
\def\IEEEkeywords{\oldIEEEkeywords\normalfont\bfseries\ignorespaces}


\newcommand*\squeezespaces[1]{% %% <- #1 is a number between 0 and 1
  \thickmuskip=\scalemuskip{\thickmuskip}{#1}%
  \medmuskip=\scalemuskip{\medmuskip}{#1}%
  \thinmuskip=\scalemuskip{\thinmuskip}{#1}%
  \nulldelimiterspace=#1\nulldelimiterspace
  \scriptspace=#1\scriptspace
}
\newcommand*\scalemuskip[2]{%
  \muexpr #1*\numexpr\dimexpr#2pt\relax\relax/65536\relax
} %% <- based on  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198966/156366

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}



\title{\LARGE \bf
Weighted
}


\author{Nas
}


%---------- Format ----------
\titleformat{\section}{\centering\normalfont\scshape}{\thesection}{0em}{.~}
%\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\scshape}{\thesubsection}{0em}{.~}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\bfseries}{}{-2em}{}[:]



\begin{document}



\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{abstract}\label{abstract}Extracting .

\end{abstract}

\IEEEkeywords{uuuu}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%




 %\vspace{-3pt}
\section{Conclusion}
In this paper, we proposed a framework 


\titleformat{\section}{\centering\normalfont\scshape}{\appendixname~\thesection }{0em}{~}
\end{document}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: you will have a misplaced command in your document selecting bold, but if you show no code no one can tell you what is wrong. Post a small one paragraph but complete document that is in bold when you do not expect that.

Comment: I get the error `! Undefined control sequence.
l.4 \overrideIEEEmargins`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think because you do not have IEEEtran.cls. I can not upload files here.

Comment: IEEEtran.cls is part of the standard tex distributions, I would have a different error if that were not there. Also do you _really_ use all these packages how long is your paper???

Comment: Actually, I guess I'm using a good portion of them. The paper is 6 pages.

Comment: don't load packages you don't use, and why specify hyperref twice graphicx  three times etc and you are using tikz and xypic within 6 pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined

```
 \def\IEEEkeywords{\oldIEEEkeywords\normalfont\bfseries\ignorespaces}
```

so `\IEEEkeywords` does not take an argument. and makes all the following text bold.

Comment: How should I fix this while keeping the IEEEkeywords?

Comment: you don't say what you want it to do, perhaps `\renewcommand\IEEkeywords[1]{{\normalfont\bfseries\oldIEEEkeywords{#1}}` @NasimBahari

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how and where to use this.

Comment: @NasimBahari use that instead of the broken  definition that I showed in the answer that is breaking your document. That said if this is for submission to an IEEE journal you should probably not change their commands, that is the whole point of a journal style, to enforce a house style. So I would just delete the bad `\def` and not change `\IEEEkeywords` at all.

Comment: Without that command, the keywords look so wrong. They are repeated multiple times. Can you please give me other suggestions if you know any?

Comment: @NasimBahari that is because you are using the wrong syntax, I just looked at the class, it clearly intends `\begin{IEEEkeywords} one, two three\end{IEEEkeywords}` redefining journal publisher commands is a really bad idea: it can seriously delay publication.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Really!