# Remove stretch and shrink (glue) from existing length

Tags: lengths

Suppose I have a length `\mylength`, defined to be

```
\setlength{\mylength}{5pt plus 1pt minus 2pt}
```

I'd like to make `\mylength` a fixed length, but keep the default length. In this example, I'd like

```
\setlength{\mylength}{5pt}
```

But what if I didn't know the definition of `\mylength`? I know I can use `\the\mylength` to have it printed in the document, which I then can inspect, but I was wondering whether there is a simple way to strip out the glue of a length.

Comment: If you use `1\mylength` the stretch and shrink components are removed.

Comment: That answers my question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a factor in front of `\mylength`, the stretch and shrink components are discarded. With

```
\newlength{\lenA}
\newlength{\lenB}

\setlength{\lenA}{5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
\setlength{\lenB}{1\lenA}
```

the length `\lenB` will be set to 5pt.

If you just need to *use* `\lenA` without stretch and shrink components, the same holds:

```
\hspace{1\lenA}
```

will make a nonflexible space.